# nodejs spawn "su user -c 'ls -la'" not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, sudo, spawn

I can not spawn a simple command line: `su username -c "ls -la"`

here is my code:

```
var childArgs = [
    'username',
    '-c',
    '"ls -la"'
];

var ph = spawn('su', childArgs);

ph.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});

ph.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr___' + data);
});

ph.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('close__' + code);
});

ph.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log('error___' + error);
});
```

output:

> stderr___bash: ls -la: command not found

is there any way to spawn this command via `nodejs` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works only if I remove double quotes

```
var childArgs = [
    'spawnuser',
    '-c',
    'ls -la'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your "ls -la" into two items in the array.

```
var childArgs = [
  'username',
  '-c',
  'ls',
  '-la'
];
```

Comment: not working: stderr___su: invalid option -- 'a' Usage: su [options] [LOGIN]